# Run ASP.net core on Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows 10 Iot

Tags: asp.net, windows-10, asp.net-core-1.0, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to run asp.net core app on Raspberry pi 3 which runs Windows10 IoT .What I have done so far is:

1. Created a simple Web Api application in Asp.net core in local Windows 10 machine using visual studio.
2. removed `type:platform` from project.json file  (for self contained deployment)
3. built and published the application using `dotnet publish -c release -r win10-arm`
4. copied the published files to UNC share folder in path
5. opened the port 5000 in pi powershell session  `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="DNX Web Server port" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=5000`
6. typed `'C:\PROGRAMS\dnxpi\RasberryService.exe'` in powershell session to pi

But it errors

```
Program 'RasberryService.exe' failed to run: The operation completed successfully.
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Did you try reading the system event log (eventvwr)?

Comment: @BabuJames no actually very limited access to eventvwr in Windows Iot .

Comment: Which tutorial did you follow?

Comment: @RitaHan not any tutorial is available for dotnetcore I was trying things of my own . [oldblog post here](https://www.hackster.io/iddi/windows-10-iot-core-publish-asp-net-web-application-d9dcd4) for dnx

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT you [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723509/webserver-on-windows-10-iot/40736483#40736483) that it is possible to deploy web service in ASP.net 5 two days ago. Is that possible now by any means? can I develop ASP.net 5 web now using old dnx ? .Thanks

Comment: I mentioned it is possible for beta version but, unfortunately, it seems no ARM [runtime supported](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core) in latest rc1 version for now. Here is a more [detailed explanation](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/PiDnx) you can reference.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1531) github issue states that ARM is not supported ,but is in the road-map of dotnet core. Keeping the issue open for future updates and folks who find the same issue.